# What would this code do? (memory management)

Tags: c++, memory-management

```
char *p = new char[200];
char *p1 = p;
char *p2 = &p[100];
delete [] p1;
```

Btw this is not a test or anything i actually need to know this :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
 // allocate memory for 200 chars
 // p points to the begining of that 
 // block
 char *p = new char[200];
 // we don't know if allocation succeeded or not
 // no null-check or exception handling

 // **Update:** Mark. Or you use std::no_throw or set_new_handler. 
 // what happens next is not guranteed

 // p1 now points to the same location as p
 char *p1 = p;

 // another pointer to char which points to the
 // 100th character of the array, note that
 // this can be treated as a pointer to an array
 // for the remaining 100-odd elements
 char *p2 = &p[100];

 // free the memory for 200 chars
 delete [] p1;

 // **Update:** Doug. T
 // [...] p and p2 are now pointing to freed memory 
 // and accessing it will be undefined behavior 
 // depending on the executing environment.
```

Comment: thx this answers my question, but is there any way to only delete the first 100 ?

Comment: You can reallocate - the normal method would be to allocate a new block of 100 bytes in size and then copy the second 100 bytes into that

Comment: No, you cannot have partitioned deletion. You have to make a second new call, copy out the part you want to save and delete the original.

Comment: @dirkgently: your second comment is not correct - if allocation failed an exception would be thrown this means that the second line is only executed if allocation had succeeded. You do not need to check for null

Comment: That's what I said, I think: that what happens next is not guranteed.

Comment: You also said "no null-check"

Comment: So? If you have disabled exceptions, you need the null check. I pointed out both methods of error checking. And proceeded to explain the rest 'assuming things went well'.

Comment: How do you disable exceptions for failed new?

Comment: You disable exceptions before compiling. Since I don't know the compiler options I mentioned both. I am failing to see the merit of this discussion.

Comment: Or you use std::no_throw or set_new_handler.  It's not normal to disable exceptions, so failure would usually terminate the program.  So it *could* fall through because it's not specified, and it would be best to clarify that.  Also, p and p2 cannot be used after the final line (not always obvious).

Comment: Nice answer. You may wish to add that p and p2 are now pointing to freed memory and accessing it will be undefined behavior depending on the executing environment.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that, but since decided against. Hnag on -- I'll update my post in a while with all the comments.

Comment: This line: char *p = new char[200]; Always, I mean ALWAYS returns a valid pointer. There is not need to check for NULL. If it fails an exception will be thrown and you will never get to the next line.